# Return different model on partial view

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm having some trouble returning a ViewBag with a list of a model to a PartialView, which is a different type of model from the ParentView, but I wish to render the result, only inside the partial view that is rendered on the Parent View. Perhaps looking at my code, will give a better understanding.

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Search()
{
        //ViewBag.Usuarios = db.User.ToList();
        return View();
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Pesquisar(UserFilter userFilter)
{
        List<UserModel> retorno = new List<UserModel>();
        ViewBag.Mensagem = "Não foi encontrado registro com os filtros informados";

        if (userFilter.Name != null)
        {
             retorno = db.User.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(userFilter.Name)).ToList();
            if (retorno != null)
            {
                ViewBag.Usuarios = retorno;
                return PartialView("Search", ViewBag.Usuarios);
            }
            return View("Search", ViewBag.Mensagem);
        }

        if (userFilter.UserID != 0)
        {
            UserModel retorn = new UserModel();
            var id = Convert.ToInt16(userFilter.UserID);
            retorn = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UserID == id);                
            return View("Details", retorn);
        }
        return View("Search", ViewBag.Mensagem);
}
```

Here is my Parent View

```
@model Sistema_ADFP.Filters.UserFilter


<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Buscar Usuário</h2>
        <form role="form" method="GET" action="/User/Pesquisar">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Nome</label>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>ID</label>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>CPF</label>
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CPF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <div class="form-group pull-right">
                <label>&ensp;</label>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    @{
        if (ViewBag.Mensagem == null)
        {
            <div id="resultadoLista">
                @{
                    Html.RenderPartial("_List");
                }
            </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    <label>Nenhum registro encontrado</label>
                        }
                    }
</body>
```

And here is my Partial View

```
<h4>Usuários</h4>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <tr class="inverse" align="center">
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Sexo</th>
            <th>Estado Civil</th>
            <th>Educação</th>
            <th>Profissão</th>
            <th>Voluntário</th>
            <th>Data Nascimento</th>
            <th>Ações</th>
        </tr>

        @if (ViewBag.Usuarios != null)
        {


            foreach (var item in ViewBag.Usuarios)
            {
                <tr class="active">
                    <td data-th="Nome"><a class="modal-ajax-link" href="#test-popup">@item.Name</a></td>
                    <td data-th="Sexo">@item.Sex</td>
                    <td data-th="EstadoCivil">@item.MaritalStatus</td>
                    <td data-th="Education" align="center">@item.Education.Description</td>
                    <td data-th="Education" align="center">@item.Profession.Name</td>
                    @if (item.Voluntary)
                    {
                        <td data-th="Voluntario" align="center">Ativo</td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td data-th="Voluntario" align="center">Inativo</td>
                    }
                    <td data-th="DataNasc" align="center">@item.BirthDate</td>

                    @* data-mfp-src="@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host:@HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Port/User/Details/2" *@

                    <td data-th="Ações" align="center">
                        <a class="btn btn-info modal-ajax-link" href='@Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit",
    new { id = @item.UserID })'><i class="icon_pencil"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger modal-ajax-link" href="#delete-modal"><i class="icon_trash_alt"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }

    </table>
</div>
```

The error that i'm getting is:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Sistema_ADFP.Models.UserModel]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'Sistema_ADFP.Filters.UserFilter'.

I understand the error reason , but I can not get to a means of resetting the flow and make it work. Does anybody knows or have a tip of what i can do ?

Comment: dont use a viewBag  you can create viewModel for your view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to fix this is by not using ViewBag and create ViewModel for your view. The ViewModel is a class for your view and will have all necessary properties for your view. So, for the sake of example, you could have a view model called:

```
public class WrapperVM
{
 public UserFilter Filter {get; set;}
 public UserModel Model {get; set;}
}
```

Thus, fill these properties and pass WrapperVM to parent view (change to @model WrapperVM) and then you can pass usermodel to partial view. I hope this helps.

Comment: And how would I use it on my view ? And the return from my controller method ?

Comment: Now I got , implementing your idea , it worked. Thanks a lot for the help !